# How to tighten abs while working out

Tags: abdominals

The trainer at my gym always asks me to tighten the ab muscles while working on the ab area. I am always confused on the right way to tighten this ab area. I breath out and push my stomach outwards while doing ab workout but am unsure if this is the right way. Can someone suggest the correct way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy peezy!

If I were to punch you, and you were ready for it, you would 'tense' up and hold your breath correct?

'Tightening' your abs work much the same way.  Don't push the stomach out, or breath out.  You actually need to inhale, and 'brace for impact'.  That's tightening the core.

Comment: +1. I have little kids who jump on my stomach, and I always imagine a flying elbow coming right for my belly before deadlifts and the such.